# Using criteriaQuery of Persistence API to query conditionally

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, criteria-api

The default generation Code, of Abstract method `findAll` of Session bean is this:

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Can we create another method in the same way, which can find all the records, `WHERE status ='1'`

How?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use cq.where()

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<T> c = cq.from(entityClass);
cq.select(c);
cq.where(cb.gt(c.get("status"), 1));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: Give error in `cq.where(cb.gt(c.get("status"), 1));` Says there is no suitable method for gt.

Comment: @mrN check the dependency or imports. Maybe you import hibernate's CriteriaQuery, not JPAs. CriteriaQuery must be imported by `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`

Comment: Please see the code in the question, I have used `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`

Comment: @mrN well... gt is method of CriteriaBuilder - cb in the code. Are you sure to use cb not cq? here is JPA [CriteriaBuilder reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html)

Comment: Yes, I am. Yes, I have implemented your way and all the package are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced the same problem, so , although it is probably not relevant anymore for OP, I will post an answer. Maybe it helps somebody else.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<T> c = cq.from(entityClass);
cq.select(c);
cq.where(cb.equal(c.get("status"), 1));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

As you see, the only difference from @dgregory's answer is in this line:

```
cq.where(cb.equal(c.get("status"), 1));
```

The function **gt()** used by @dgregory instead of **equal()** tests whether its first argument is **greater than** the second argument, which implies that the arguments must be **numbers**. However, the **status** column in your database is obviously a **char**, so the exception is thrown. The meaning of this exception is that there is no gt() method with first argument as a char, although this method exists with the numeric first argument.

Not to mention that, even if such a method existed, this is not what you expected from your query.